# Get different result when querying "SELECT text(textsend_i('一'));" between pgAdmin and other PostgreSQL IDEs

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I met a problem of searching Chinese words '一' on pgAdmin4.

When I used terminal or other SQL IDEs the query result is 'e4b880'(Hex UTF-8 bytes), but pgAdmin4 returned '344\270\200'(Octal UTF-8 bytes), and our database's stored data is 'e4b880' so that I cannot get the query result by using pgAdmin4, I try to change the pgsql's client encoding but the situation is not changed, really hope someone can give me some advises, thanks.

```
select text(textsend_i('一'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same correct value.

The difference is that in the pgAdmin session, the parameter `bytea_output` is set to `escape`, while in the other sessions it is set to its default value `hex`.

Comment: Thanks to your response, is there any way to make pgAdmin use hex?

Comment: You could set the parameter correctly and use an explicit cast to `text`. I don't know pgAdmin well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laurenz's advise, finally I find out the method to resolve my problem on pgAdmin4.

```
SELECT encode(convert_to('一', 'UTF-8'), 'HEX')
```